# Unable to load https websites on safari

Tags: macos, safari

I have an old iMac running OSX 10.7.5/Safari 6.1.6.

Due to some programs on that system & generally slow systems on similar iMacs with more recent OSX version **I do not want to update to a newer OSX**

I have several websites forcing https which I can no longer access as safari says "Safari can not open the page …, as safari can not establish a secure connection to …" (translated from german).

Chrome and Firefox on the same machine are able to open these pages, as are more recent Safaris on more recent machines.

I tried downloading/installing the root certificate in the keychain, but this did not help.

Are there some security updates I'm not getting via normal system updates which could fix this?

For example: [www.biblio.lu](http://www.biblio.lu)

Comment: Please add an example https site!

Comment: here I found last Opera/Firefox/Chrome for Lion ftp://86.57.150.15/Lion/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari 6/OS X doesn't support TLSv1.2. Sites only supporting the TLSv1.2 protocol like [biblio.lu](https://www.biblio.lu/) won't work in Safari 6.

You can cross-check/compare your browser's result at [SSL Client Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html)
with the SSL Server Test (e.g. [SSL Server Test testing biblio.lu](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.biblio.lu)).

No supported protocols overlap between Safari 6.1.6/Mac OS X 10.7.5:

[image]

and biblio.lu

[image]

so no https access! Google Chrome 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) - the last Google Chrome version supporting 10.6/10.7/10.8 works though.

Answer (score 0):

what version of safari are you using?

As mentioned on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53562/safari-cant-connect-to-https) post by **gentmatt**, it can be a problem with safari's version.

Solution proposed by **gentmatt** was to delete this file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist
```

Comment: OSX 10.7.5/Safari 6.1.6  None of the solutions proposed in that post helped

Comment: @Pit, i've found some information and a possible solution here [Solution](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/26/fix-safari-cant-verify-website-error/).